# Moving data to and from viewcontrollers when NOT using storyboard (so without segues), how do you actually implement those delegates? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, delegates, protocols

I'm trying to work through this tutorial: https://cocoacasts.com/implement-the-nsfetchedresultscontrollerdelegate-protocol-with-swift-3 
But I found him using the `Storyboard` and `segues` to move data between `ViewControllers`. Yet I can not find a proper and safe way to move data from one `UIViewController` and another.

Everyone always throws around *'oh you just need a delegate and protocol'* or *'use singletons'* or *'please never use singletons'*. All I could find in the last six hours of reading on protocols and delegates are superficial examples of weddings, puppies and tanks, but nowhere a proper way to do this. 
The only thing I could find is in objective-C, which I sadly don't read or write. Even the questions on Stackoverflow that asked the same question don't have the answer, since the explanation is usually vague and in the category of *'I do it like this because it works, you too should do it like this. It works now.'*, without further explanation.

Now moving something towards a VC when you use the `present()` function is easy, but backwards is the real problem, since the same trick doesn't work when you use `dismiss()` or `popViewController()`.

Nowhere can I find a proper way to move data (like in the tutorial's case an NSManagedObjectContext object) between VCs with delegates and protocols.

Surely I'm not the only one wondering, and a good explanation of the different ways with some example code would be helpful for others than me as well.

---

So my questions remain: **How do you move information between viewControllers without Storyboard and without Segues in Swift? And if delegates and protocols are the answer, what is the proper way to do this?**

EDIT: it is different from the other question on this topic ([Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)) because this question is asked in Swift, not in Objective-C

Comment: How are you moving data back with a segue? That sounds like you are doing segues incorrectly. There is no single answer to this. Yes, use a singleton, use a delegate, use a protocol, use a redux data store, use core data, the answer to this question is up to you. That’s all part of designing and developing an app.

Comment: Note that storyboards and segues are a relatively recent addition to iOS in general. What have you tried so far? Also... “I don’t read objective c” is a poor excuse. It should not matter what language it is. The main idea is the iOS implementation of it.

Comment: @rmaddy it’s not a duplicate, the question and answers in the other one uses storyboard and segues.

Comment: There are many answers in the duplicate. Many do not use storyboards or segues. Many are in Swift.